AWS ALB sub directory query gets Refused to Connect error
I currently have my Cloud Infrastructured Configured as followed:
Route 53 resolves domain.name to DNS of the ALB
ALB has a listener on 443. The only 1 rule I have is to forward all to my Target Group (EC2 instances that run WordPress) on 80.
The error I currently faces is Refused Connection when I try to navigate to the sub directory on the path, ex: domain.name/wp-login.
I read somewhere that this is related to path based routing, so I added another condition in my rule: Path is /wp* . But it is still isn't working.
All help and advice are greatly appreciated.
Added a condition: Path is /wp* to the rule.
Expect to be able to navigate to all sub directories on WordPress

If you've already got requests flowing from browser -> ALB -> ec2 then there's no need for additional rules.
Where are you seeing these connection refused errors, is this coming from a browser?

Hi Ashley, yes it’s coming from the browser. I suspect it might be because of Route53 DNS. I only have a record of the domain name pointing to ALB. But no /* wildcard. Is that where my issue is? Same thing in my ACM, should I put a /* wildcard in my ACM as well?

I wouldn't think so, but with basic connectivity testing/troubleshooting, especially with ALBs I wouldn't use a browser, there's too many variables.
For basic connectivity:
telnet <example.com> 443
If that works then you've got your ALB setup and you've got a target listening. Next:
curl -v https://example.com
Check the headers and the response. This will tell you if the target is actually processing the request.
You mentioned that subdirectories aren't working, so try
curl -v https://example.com/subdir
This will give you a bit more info on what's going on

When I first installed apache2 on the EC2 and set up ALB to direct traffic to it, I was able to see the staging page when I typed in the domain.name in the browser. I edited the secgroup for the ALB, to allows 443 outbound to everywhere. I ran curl -v and received a 200 status code. So I then tried accessing it from the browser, but it looks like I only got a plain HTML with no css

your SG should allow 'all' outbound, not 443 outbound. You can only guarantee that 443 is the incoming port, not the outgoing port.
Now as for your CSS not loading, that sounds like an apache configuration problem (perhaps), so treat that as a separate issue

Hey Ashley, so I fixed my problem :) Thank you for responding back.
So first, I followed your advice to allow outbound all traffic to all ipv4. Not sure if this is what you meant. Got a warning from AWS tho.
Second, I also followed your second advice to treat the CSS breaking issue as a separate thing. It turns out because I have SSL on my ALB, I found another post from this: "https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75921/ssl-breaks-wordpress-css", basically just have to add a line in the wp-config.php.
Again, thank you so much for your help!
